# Microsoft Word/Excel: Excel Data -> Word Template

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I've got an excel sheet with the following 2 columns:

1. Full Name
2. Organization/Company Affiliation

Both text only. I'm looking to print out nametags for the 200 or so entries in the spreadsheet, and am hoping to both create a "template" in word to then en-masse link the Excel data into. To rephrase: I'm hoping to set it up to auto generate a document that could then be printed onto a blank sheet of name tag stickers.

What's the best way to go about this?

For reference, the sheets of name-tag stickers are 8.5x11 and have 10 tags on them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Mailings" ribbon and select "Start Mail Merge", which will walk you through the process.